# Modifying step in a running engagement program

Tags: pardot

I have a running engagement program in Pardot that has all prospects waiting for 90 days.  I want to change the number of days of that step to make it start today.

I have calculated that only 13 waiting days are required for the prospects to move to the next step.  So I paused the program, adjusted the number of days to 13 and started the program again. They should have moved to the next step yesterday, but they are still waiting on the 13 dayts count...

Will the count of the number of days be reset to zero after a change or will it continue counting from where it was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The count of the number of days in a step is kept for each prospect.  The hours are important as well, so if a prospect enters in a step at 12:00, the one day will be completed the next at 12:00 as well.

If you want to ignore the count, instead of reducing the number of days, just select to run the step immediately.